how to append ACF field data using one of the following filter/ hooks
using a plugin which lists the following as filters/hooks to append data:
// Data Filters
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_title', $this->post->post_title);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_short_description', do_shortcode($this->post->post_excerpt));
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_price', $price);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_description', $this->post->post_content);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_meta_keys', $temp);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_html', $this->get_first_layout(), $this->data->ID); 

// Custom HTML 
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_before_product_info_html', '', $this->data->ID); 
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_after_product_info_html', '', $this->data->ID); 

// HTML Strings
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_description_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_attributes_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_attributes_html', ob_end_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_reviews_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_upsells_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_gallery_images_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);
apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_product_variations_html', ob_get_clean(), $this->data->ID);

i have an ACF field for products single with the name append_to_pdf_cut_sheet whose data i'd like to append for example to apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_after_product_info_html', '', $this->data->ID);.
what i tried to no avail - total novice here:
$custom_field_value = get_field('append_to_pdf_cut_sheet', $this->data->ID);

if ($custom_field_value) {
    $custom_field_value = apply_filters('woocommerce_print_products_after_product_info_html', $custom_field_value, $this->data->ID);
    echo $custom_field_value;
}

